# Create League Table Wordpress League Archive Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress plugin for the display of archived league information for a football league, they will be using a new league management software going forward so the purpose of the plugin is to only display previous season/league information. 
I am trying to create league tables for the competitions in each season but currently, my code is only returning fixtures for the first competition. How do I loop through the data correctly in order to return information for each competition?

```
function generateLeagueTable($atts)
{
   $archiveDB = new wpdb('database_archive','password','database_archive','host');
   $id = $atts['id'];
   $competitionsID = $archiveDB->get_results("select * from tblHFLClubCompetitionLink where seasonid = $id");
   $removeDuplicates = array_unique($competitionsID, SORT_REGULAR);
   foreach ($removeDuplicates as $competitionID) :
  $compid = $competitionID->competitionid;
  d($compid);
  $compname = $archiveDB->get_results("select name from tblHFLCompetition where competitionid = $compid");
 echo "<h3>" . $name->name . "</h3>";
  $fixtures = $archiveDB->get_results("select * from tblHFLFixture WHERE seasonid = $id AND competitionid = $compid");
  d($fixtures);
 $clubids = array();
 $clubscores = array();

 foreach ($fixtures as $fixture) :
      $clubids[] = $fixture->homeclubid;
      $clubids[] = $fixture->awayclubid;

     $goalsHome = $fixture->homegoals;
     $goalsAway = $fixture->awaygoals;
     $addPtsHC = "";
     $addPtsAC = "";
     if ($goalsHome>$goalsAway)
     {
         $addPtsHC ="3";
         $addPtsAC = "0";
         $clubscores[] = array("team" => $fixture->homeclubid, "W" => "1", "D" => '0', "L" => "0", "Pts" => "3");
         $clubscores[] = array("team" => $fixture->awayclubid, "W" => "0", "D" => '0', "L" => "1", "Pts" => "0");
     }
     else if ($goalsHome<$goalsAway)
     {
         $addPtsHC ="3";
         $addPtsAC = "0"; 
         $clubscores[] = array("team" => $fixture->homeclubid, "W" => "0", "D" => '0', "L" => "1", "Pts" => "0");
         $clubscores[] = array("team" => $fixture->awayclubid, "W" => "1", "D" => '0', "L" => "0", "Pts" => "3");
     }
     else if ($goalsHome==$goalsAway)
     {
        $addPtsHC ="1";
        $addPtsAC = "1"; 
        $clubscores[] = array("team" => $fixture->homeclubid, "W" => "0", "D" => '1', "L" => "0", "Pts" => "1");
        $clubscores[] = array("team" => $fixture->awayclubid, "W" => "0", "D" => '1', "L" => "0", "Pts" => "1");
     }

      endforeach;


       d($clubscores);

       $result = array();
       foreach($clubscores as $k => $v) :
       $id = $v['team'];
           $result[$id] [] = $v['W'];

       endforeach;
       d($result);
       $new = array();
       foreach($result as $key => $value) :

           $new[] = array('id' => $key, 'W' => array_sum($value), 'D' => array_sum($value), 'L' => array_sum($value), "Pts" => array_sum($value));
           endforeach;

       d($new);


  endforeach;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of your tables where you get the data?

Comment: thanks for messaging, I have added images of the database tables to the original post

Comment: what result do you want to get?

Comment: I am trying to create a table that shows for each team Won, Drawn, Lost and Played and have them display in order.